# The least sum of numbers in nx3 array so that every column and row is represented there

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, greedy

This is a part of algorithmic problem I'm fighting with for the 3rd day in the row. So we are given an array 3xn (n rows, 3 columns). We need to find the least sum such:

- we only pick one element from each row,
- each row must be represented, so there has to be exactly one number from each row in such sum,
- each column must be represent, so there has to be at least one number located 1st column, at least one located in the 2nd column, and at least one in the 3rd column.

Let's take that array to illustrate the problem:

```
6 2 4
8 7 5
6 2 4
9 6 5
```

The least sum in that case is `8 (1st column, 2nd row) + 2 (2nd column, 1st row) + 5 (3rd column,4th row) + 2 (2nd column,3rd row) = 17`

I tried solving that in such greedy way that I created three copies of that array, sorted each of them by the respective column and then tried in `3!` ways to make the least sum of the three numbers, and add the minimums for the rest, but then solution for the above case would be:

`6 (1st column, 3rd row) + 2 (2nd column, 1st row) + 5 (3rd column, 4th row) + remaining 5 (3rd column, 2nd row) = 18` So that way of greedy approach proved to be unsuccessful. Would anyone suggest what should I change in my approach to make it the working one?

Comment: Did you try my solution or is there still anything unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all rows, and in each row, pick the least element of that row. (This is O(n).)
Now there are 3 possibilities:

1. The picked elements cover all 3 columns. We are done.
2. The picked elements cover 2 columns:

   - Go through all rows again and consider the difference between the element in the missing row and the picked element.
   - Find the row with the minimum difference and switch the choice in that row. We are done. (This is O(n).)
3. The picked elements cover only 1 column:

   - Go through all rows again and consider the differences between the element in the first missing row and the picked element, and between the element in the second missing row and the picked element.
   - Find the 2 rows with the smallest and second smallest difference between the element in the first missing row and the picked element.
   - Find the 2 rows with the smallest and second smallest difference between the element in the second missing row and the picked element.
   - Now you just have to consider the four possibilities of switching and choose which one is better (and satisfies the constraints). We are done. (This is done in O(n).)